# Navigation Drawer for Web Application

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, web-applications, navigation-drawer

So I am developing a Web Application and I am looking for a way to create a navigation drawer (bootstrap or otherwise) and I have only one requirement from my stakeholder which is, when the drawer is collapsed/closed I need the font awesome icons to still show. And then when I open the drawer the icons should stay in the same place and the text beside each icon should appear as the drawer rolls out.

I could only find one example of this online, please see the link below:

https://jhipster.github.io/

Hoping you can help. 
Thanks :)

Edit:
Does anyone know any resources/plugins/way that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Can you phrase this as a question please?

Comment: Done. See above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this example could be a good guide to follow, it seems to meet your requirements listed above.

https://codepen.io/JFarrow/pen/fFrpg

HTML:

```
  </head>
  <body><div class="area"></div><nav class="main-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="nav-text">
                        Dashboard
                    </span>
                </a>

            </li>
            <li class="has-subnav">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="nav-text">
                        UI Components
                    </span>
                </a>

            </li>
            <li class="has-subnav">
                <a href="#">
                   <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="nav-text">
                        Forms
                    </span>
                </a>

            </li>
            <li class="has-subnav">
                <a href="#">
                   <i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="nav-text">
                        Pages
                    </span>
                </a>

            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="nav-text">
                        Graphs and Statistics
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-font fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="nav-text">
                        Typography and Icons
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="#">
                   <i class="fa fa-table fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="nav-text">
                        Tables
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="nav-text">
                        Maps
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                   <i class="fa fa-info fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="nav-text">
                        Documentation
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="logout">
            <li>
               <a href="#">
                     <i class="fa fa-power-off fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="nav-text">
                        Logout
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>  
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);
}
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300);
.fa-2x {
font-size: 2em;
}
.fa {
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
width: 60px;
height: 36px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size:20px;
}


.main-menu:hover,nav.main-menu.expanded {
width:250px;
overflow:visible;
}

.main-menu {
background:#fbfbfb;
border-right:1px solid #e5e5e5;
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
height:100%;
left:0;
width:60px;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition:width .05s linear;
transition:width .05s linear;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
z-index:1000;
}

.main-menu>ul {
margin:7px 0;
}

.main-menu li {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:250px;
}

.main-menu li>a {
position:relative;
display:table;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
color:#999;
 font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
transition:all .1s linear;

}

.main-menu .nav-icon {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
width:60px;
height:36px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size:18px;
}

.main-menu .nav-text {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
width:190px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.main-menu>ul.logout {
position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover {
overflow-y:hidden;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover:hover {
overflow-y:auto;
overflow:visible;
}

a:hover,a:focus {
text-decoration:none;
}

nav {
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
-o-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
}

nav ul,nav li {
outline:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.main-menu li:hover>a,nav.main-menu li.active>a,.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,.dropdown-menu>.active>a,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,.no-touch .dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li:hover a,.dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li.active a {
color:#fff;
background-color:#5fa2db;
}
.area {
float: left;
background: #e2e2e2;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Titillium WebLight'), local('TitilliumWeb-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/titilliumweb/v2/anMUvcNT0H1YN4FII8wpr24bNCNEoFTpS2BTjF6FB5E.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Comment: That appears to be exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for the help :)